# remote app user login in windows server 2012 r2

Tags: user-accounts, windows-server-2012, remote

I have a windows server 2012 r2 and I need to define that everytime a user connects to a remote app, this connection must start from 0.

Example:

First step: user1 connects from a computer and it works fine.

Second step: user1 connects from a different computer and the first connection closes, but the second one opens with everything the other connection had open before.

how can I avoid this? The second connection must be new, not the same.

Comment: If this is a terminal server make sure your application is designed to work on that environment. Ask the application designer.

Comment: @Fixitrod It is a terminal server and the application works correctly. The issue is with the user when login twice. I want that every time the user closes the connection to automatically logoff his/her session.

Comment: Oh, that's a completely diffrent question but I can help you with that. In the terminal server configuration settings for this. I'll put an answer for that question.

Answer (score 0):

You can make people's connection logoff with settings in group policy or with the Remote Desktop Session Host.

Everything below can be found [at this technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272.aspx)

In group policy there are two areas for these settings.

For user settings:

In group policy expand the following under user config.

```
Configuration, Policies, Administrative, Templates, Windows Components, Remote Desktop Services, Remote Desktop Session Host, Session Time LimitsUser
```

For the computer settings:

In group policy expand the following under computer config

```
Configuration, Policies, Administrative Templates, Windows Components, Remote Desktop Services, Remote Desktop Session Host, Session Time Limits
```

For the Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration you can get all the commands [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272.aspx)
But, there is the following command you could set very low and they will be logged off even if they just close the session.

End a disconnected session

> Specify the maximum amount of time >that a disconnected user session is >kept active on the RD Session Host >server. If you specify "Never," the user's >disconnected session is maintained >for an unlimited time.
>
> When a session is in a disconnected >state, running programs are kept >active even though the user is no >longer actively connected.